# How to access relation in ajax content

Tags: ajax, laravel

When i want to get username in Laravel i do `$post->user->name;`, how would i do this in context of ajax.

```
public function getDataByAjax(Request $request){
    $posts =  Post::first()->approved()->published()->take(6)->get();

    if ($request->ajax()) {
        return response()->json([ 
            'success' => "OK",
            'data'    => $posts, 
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: try to use `Post::first()->with(['user'])->...`

Comment: Did the answer help you or do you still have problems?

Answer (score 2):

Your `Post.php` response would look like so.

```
{
    'title' => 'Your Post',
    ...
}
```

To include relation, you can use `with()`. This will eager load a relationship and tell the model to include it when it is transformed. So the following code.

```
$posts =  Post::with('user')->approved()->published()->take(6)->get();
```

Will produce the following `JSON`.

```
{
    'title' => 'Your Post',
    'user' => {
        'name' => 'Martin'
    }
}
```

Comment: that `with` isn't going to be applied to the result since `first()` returns a model, which is the result of the query that `with` is applied to, then calling the `approved()` scope would cause a new builder instance

Comment: Aghrr yh didnt see that :) updated the question, don't see the point of the first(), seems like without it would be fine.

Comment: yea there is no point to the `first`, just a wasted query :-)